# switching between implementation and header files in vi

Tags: xcode, vim

In Xcode when editing either an implementation or header file there is a shortcut key to quickly switch to its counterpart. Can this be done in vi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a big long list of different ways of doing this:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easily_switch_between_source_and_header_file

I like the "Single line solution" one best - their example works only if your .h and .c files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 6):

In Vim, you can use the [A plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31). I have no idea about Vi though.